# Rails 4 - Creating Ancestry Tree with Associations - General Process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, model-associations, ancestry

~~> FYI I am not asking for someone to tell me what to do, but rather direct me as I want to go through the learning experience. Thank you! <~~

Rails beginner here. I've been trying to create a content management application with news articles and things are going well. My biggest obstacle so far is linking my articles with their categories. After many hours of googling and learning, I think I need some big brother help.

This is what I'm attempting:

1. I have articles that can belong to multiple categories, and categories can have multiple articles. So I want to set up a many-to-many association.
2. I also want users to be able to specify which category an article belongs to when they create a new article via the form. I've tried using collection_select in my form and it seems promising. The form should be able to select from subcategories too.
3. Finally, I want to create a navigational tree to see what articles belong to what category (I played around with the Ancestry gem). The tree should follow the associations specified in the form. There can be multiple depths, for example: Science News(category) > Materials Engineering(category) > Graphene(article)

I am confused on the general process of how to accomplish all this. I've tried a variety of approaches but it seems like every attempt was missing some minor but vital step. Could a more experienced Rails programmer please enlighten me on how to do this?

- Rails 4.20
- Ruby 2.1.5

-.-------------------------------------------------

-.------SOLUTION---------------------

-.-------------------------------------------------

After much gruel and grind, I've figured out a solution. Here is a step by step. Hopefully this will save a lot of headache for anyone else with the same problem!

1a. You'll want to first create a join table for many-to-many associations. In cmd type $rails g model Categorizations.

1b.Inside your newly generated migration file, change it to:

```
class CreateCategorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :categorizations do |t|
      t.integer :article_id
      t.integer :category_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :categorizations, ['article_id', 'category_id']
  end
  def down
    drop_table :categorizations
  end
end
```

1c. Inside your models, change it to:

Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :category, :through=> :categorizations
end
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :article, :through=> :categorizations
end
```

Categorization model:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :category
end
```

1d. Run $rake db:migrate

2a. Now for part 2, we will go to the article views. Inside the _form, add:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label(:category_id, "Reference *") %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.order(:title), :id, :title)%>
</div>
```

2b. Also include in your article show:

```
<tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <td><%= link_to @article.category_id, category_path(:id=>@article.category_id)%></td>
</tr>
```

2c. @article.category_id is not yet an attribute of article. I was stuck here for a long time. Turns out you have to add that attribute in seperately, so on cmd run $rails g migration AddIdToArticles. Your new migration should look like:

```
class AddIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :articles, :category_id, :integer
  end

  def down
    remove_column :articles, :category_id
  end
end
```

2d. Run $rake db:migrate. Next, we must allow :category_id through rails strong parameters, so add that into the articles controller.

I have not gotten this far yet. Will update once I figure it out!

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the solution, either 1) edit an answer to include the additional info information that made it work for you, or 2) Add your own answer to the question ... Both are valid, and you can use whichever you feel is more appropriate... I have rolled back the edit (but you can still see it if you view the edit history if you click on 'Edited X minutes ago').

Comment: Carpetsmoker, I am confused. Adding an answer to my own question (option 2) would that be commenting or adding to the bottom? I added to the bottom

Comment: Hi @nvrpicurnose. First of all, when you have a solution you need to add the solution as an answer to your own question. Second of all, has_many :category & has_many :article doesn't make any sense, which makes me think your own solution was never tested and you just throw ideas there. Third of all you ended with "I have not gotten this far yet". At the end you didn't put any solution at all. That's why I downvoted your question, you should learn how to use StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. If each article belongs to *a single* category, then isn't that simply a has_many association from category to article?
2. collection_select indeed seems like a good way to go.
3. Wouldn't the category to article tree only be a depth of two? I don't see a need for the ancestry gem.

Comment: I guess I wasnt too clear (question updated). Articles can belong to multiple categories and the category depth could be more than just 2. For example, World News > Science Research > Materials Engineering

Comment: Okay, so categories can belong to categories, so ancestry is a good choice. Then create join tables for the categories so like category_memberships that each have an article_id and a category_id. Can articles belong to categories across multiple tree leaves or just the parents of the bottom category?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean exactly by tree leaves, but articles can only belong to the last subcategory in the ancestry. They would rely on the ancestry line to show where their root is